# Selinium web driver- Unable to locate href

Tags: selenium, webdriver, href

I trying to locate a link "Taschen" in the below code(`<a data-flyout-target="handbags" title="Taschen" href="#">Taschen</a>`) using selinium webdriver. Could anyone please guide me

```
 <a data-flyout-target="handbags" title="Taschen" href="#">Taschen</a>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any code here.

Answer (score 2):

Here are your choices:

```
By.className 
By.cssSelector 
By.id 
By.linkText 
By.name 
By.partialLinkText 
By.tagName 
By.xpath
```

So assuming that "Taschen" is partial link text

```
WebElement aLink = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Taschen"));
```

If you haven't bothered with page loads and proper implicit waits then this might work better

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement aLink = wait.until(
  ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.partialLinkText("Taschen"))
);
aLink.click();
```

You are not using java?  Update your question to show your code and add a language tag to your question. Your brain isn't a network connected device and we only know what you tell us. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the XPath as below:-

```
//a[@title='Taschen']/text()
```

Code will be as below:-

```
    WebElement tash = driver.findElement(By.xpath("Taschen"));
```

If you need to get the text then you can use :-

```
 String tash = driver.findElement(By.xpath("Taschen")).getText();
```

You can also use the contains function in XPath

```
//a[contains(.,'Taschen')]
```

Hope it will help you :)